# Is there a way to remove "input sockets" from a custom node group?

Tags: node-editor

I made a node group but i only want to have the parameter and remove its input socket, is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Edit your group and expand the N-menu in the material nodes windows and select the socket you want to remove. Then press the X beside the name.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. But if i do that i remove the exposed parameters too. I just want to remove the "input socket" where you plug stuff, and keep the parameters

Comment: Then I don't know... Sorry for missing that detail in your question :-P

Comment: I don't think that is possible, at least not without without some python scripting

Answer (score -2):

you can do it via python scripting, or buried in the UI: in the outliner in "Data API" view, search for the desired input and check "Hide"

Comment: It would be great if you would show in your answer how to accomplish this in Python and the Data API view. As of now this will likely not help other users, since if they did not previously know about these option they will likely not know how to use them either.